# Can i keep instances of class inside enum?

Tags: c#

Everywhere i meet enums with string as a value and int as an index, but what if i want to keep instances inside enum like this:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
   new Person("John"),
   new Person("Jack")
}
```

Is it possible?
Just asking

//Edit 2019: I was so stupid then, should have used as a array

Comment: This is simply not possible. You should probably use a class to hold the instances.

Comment: `...i meet enums with string as a value` Those are not strings - those are constants

Comment: What you have posted makes no sense and won't compile. If you explained what you are trying to accomplish with it we may be able to help you.

Comment: Docs say no: _"An enumeration is a set of named constants whose underlying type is any integral type..."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: If you want to map an `int` to a `Person`, you might use `Dictionary<int, Person>`.

Comment: Are you possibly thinking that C# enums are Java enums? They are not.

Comment: Whilst you cannot assign an instance of an object to an enum, you may be able to define a custom attribute containing the properties that you intended to put on your person class and attribute the enum value with their equivalent. But there is no doubt a more straight forward way to achieve what you are asking about. If you update with your specific challenge that led you to try to do this, maybe a better solution will emerge.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done.

> An enum type is a distinct value type (§4.1) that declares a set of named constants.
>
> The body of an enum type declaration defines zero or more enum members, which are the named constants of the enum type. No two enum members can have the same name.
>
> Each enum member has an associated constant value. The type of this value is the underlying type for the containing enum. The constant value for each enum member must be in the range of the underlying type for the enum.

Enums have members that are named constants and an associated constant value. Each Enum also has an underlying type, which defaults to `int`. The constant values can be given explicitly, or they can be implicit.

```
enum Color 
{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green
}
```

is equivalent to

```
enum Color : int 
{
    Red = 0,
    Blue = 1,
    Green = 2
}
```

A class instance, such as `new Person("Jack");` is not a constant, and not valid as an enum member or value.

Beyond just the validity of trying to do this, I'm not certain how you would expect this to be used. Are you looking to be able to access a `TestEnum.Jack` and retrieve your `Person("Jack")` instance? If so, you could accomplish something similar to this with a class that has static readonly properties with the correct defaults provided.

```
public static class People {
    public static Person Jack {get;} = new Person("Jack");
    public static Person John {get;} = new Person("John");
}
```

You can now get your person instances with `People.John` and `People.Jack`.
This can lead into issues if the `Person` class is mutable, despite these properties being readonly.